# How to map element to several attributes in mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, mat-icon

Given a specific object, I'd like to show its enum string value, and an icon of a specific color in a mat-table.

For example, I have a data class which has an enum status:

```js
export enum Status {
  Todo = 'Todo',
  InProgress = 'In Progress',
  Done = 'Done'
}

export interface DataItem {
  id: number;
  status: Status;  // that custom enum from above
}
```

and the end result for a list of items should be something like:

```html
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><mat-icon class='gray;' title='Todo'> build </mat-icon></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><mat-icon class='yellow;' title='InProgress'> hourglass_empty</mat-icon></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td><mat-icon class='green;' title='Todo'>check_circle</mat-icon></td>
</tr>
```

Specifically, I'd like to set:

1. The icon color (using a css class or directly),
2. The icon name (using material icons),
3. `title` attribute (using the enum value).

So my approach is basically to create several methods which will return these three attributes for the template:

```js
// in mytable.component.ts

  getIconName(item : DataItem) {
    switch (item.status) {
      case Status.Todo: 
        return "build";
      case Status.InProgress:
        return "hourglass_empty";
      case Status.Done:
        return "check_circle";
    }
  }
  
  getClass(item : DataItem) {
    switch (item.status) {
      case Status.Todo: 
        return "gray";
      case Status.InProgress:
        return "yellow";
      case Status.Done:
        return "green";
    }
  }
  
  getTitle(item : DataItem) {
    switch (item.status) {
      case Status.Todo: 
        return "To Do";
      case Status.InProgress:
        return "In Progress";
      case Status.Done:
        return "Done";
    }
  }
```

And then just call these methods in the template, sort of:

```html
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" 
    title="{{getTitle(element)}}" 
    class="{{getClass(element)}}">
  <mat-icon> {{getIcon(element)}} </mat-icon>
</mat-cell>
```

But I feel like I am doing something wrong and this should all be done without calling these methods directly.

Comment: Yes, use a pipe instead of calling these methods

Comment: @Double-expresso: thanks! So, the idea is to create a pipe which will convert the `DataItem` into an entirely different object, which will contain all these properties?

Comment: Or you have a pipe right to the value you want - `title={{ element | itemTitle }}` or `title={{ element.status | itemTitle }}`. That'll be more efficient than your current solution because [Angular assumes pipes are *pure*](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#detecting-pure-changes-to-primitives-and-object-references), whereas the methods will be called a lot.

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
export enum Status {
  Todo = 'Todo',
  InProgress = 'In Progress',
  Done = 'Done'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  status = Status;

  constructor() {}
}
```

,

```
<td>
  <mat-icon
    class="{{item.status == status.Todo ? 'gray' : item.status == status.Done ? 'green' : 'yellow'}}"
    title="{{status.Todo}}">
    {{item.status == status.Todo ? 'build' : item.status == status.Done ? 'check_circle' : 'hourglass_empty'}}
  </mat-icon>
</td>
```

check title is correct or not because I am not sure you want it as "To Do" or "Todo"

here is StackBlitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qkhtsx